# Large gap between fascia and roof deck / drip edge

Tags: roof, gutters, gap, flashing, fascia

After re-securing and re-sloping a gutter (because I noticed the dormer roof is not actually level and the side opposite the downspout is lower), I noticed a considerable gap above the gutter and fascia and below the drip edge and roof deck. It’s about 1-2” (I can see the bottoms of roofing staples inside). I’m worried about rodents, birds, bats, bees/wasps getting inside as well as potential water damage.
How might I go about covering this gap? The roof ridge is vented, so I doubt this large of a gap here is needed for ventilation.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just re-added the photos, looks like they failed to upload the first time.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't show us much of what's _behind_ the gutter. Also unfortunately, the fix should've happened while you had the gutters down (or before re-fastening).

Comment: What's going on with that drip edge? It's odd that it leans out the way it does.

Comment: Note, I didn’t take the gutter all the way off, just put some new screws in the fascia on the right side where it was hanging and then removed the gutter screws on the left side to lower the gutter down about an inch before screwing them back in. It’s pretty high up for me, so it’s difficult to do anything too drastic.

Comment: might be your soffit intake for your ridge output.

Comment: Perhaps you need to re-fascia the dormer?